# React router v6. Вопрос по маршрутам - UseNavigate генерирует некорректный маршрут

Tags: react-router

Всем привет! Я обновил все пакеты в текущем проекте. Раньше для навигации использовалось UseHistory.push, сейчас UseNavigate. И у меня есть участок кода, где с текущей страницы при нажатии на кнопку переходим на другую:

```
navigate('/registration/');
```

Но он меня перекидывает вот по какому адресу: http://localhost:3000/#/registration/ Т.е. откуда-то в путь добавляется /# Естественно, мне нужно, чтобы кидал просто в регистрацию без лишней решетки: http://localhost:3000/registration/ Как от этого избавиться и в чем вообще может быть причина своевольного добавления решетки?

Comment: `navigate('/registration');`

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Попробуйте так как я написал

Comment: Нет, вообще без изменений. пробовал и вообще без слешей: navigate('registration')